# Ubuntu unallocated partition after windows 10 update

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, windows-10

I updated windows 10 yesterday to the Creators Update and after that my dual boot system with 16.04 can't boot to any OS showing me a black screen indicating grub rescue error. Then I tried to boot ubuntu from a USB memory and see what happened. Gparted is showing the linux partition highlighted in the image as "unallocated space", so I can't mount the partition in live mode and try to access it:

[Gparted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1hh3.png)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print | grep Table
Partition Table: msdos
```

Trying gdisk the linux partition is again not listed:

```
root@ubuntu:~# gdisk /dev/sda -l
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 1465149168 sectors, 698.6 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 7BD32B39-CD4A-4ECB-9844-0D4F7E7B9FFC
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1465149134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 314463607 sectors (149.9 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1026047   500.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2         1026048      1115300149   531.3 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   3      1115301888      1116983295   821.0 MiB   2700  Windows RE
   5      1431441408      1465147391   16.1 GiB    8200  Linux swap
root@ubuntu:~#

root@ubuntu:~# gdisk /dev/sda
...
Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 314463607 free sectors (149.9 GiB) available in 4
segments, the largest of which is 314458112 (149.9 GiB) in size.

Command (? for help):
```

I don't have much experience with linux partitions, but is it possible to recover the linux partition in this case and boot again? There is no critical data to save, the work I was doing there has been saved to git, but I would like to avoid the time consuming task of setting up the system again.

Answer (score 0):

Gosh darn it... Microsoft hasn't fixed that horrible bug yet? It was also in the Microsoft Anniversary Update.

You can boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and install `testdisk` and see if you can recover your partition.

For help, please see http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step